# Deploy on Heroku using Scalatra

Tags: scala, heroku, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

I am trying to deploy my Scalatra web application in heroku but I am having one problem.

My application works in local with SBT and using "heroku local web". I am using heroku sbt plugin.

When I use "sbt stage deployHeroku" the application is uploaded and started properly, obtaining:

---

```
user@user-X550JF:~/Documents/SOFT/cloudrobe$ sbt stage deployHeroku
Detected sbt version 0.13.9
....
....
[info] Packaging /home/user/Documents/SOFT/cloudrobe/target/scala-2.11/cloudrobe_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed May 25, 2016 1:04:51 AM
[info] -----> Packaging application...
[info]        - app: cloudrobe
[info]        - including: target/universal/stage/
[info] -----> Creating build...
[info]        - file: target/heroku/slug.tgz
[info]        - size: 45MB
[info] -----> Uploading slug... (100%)
[info]        - success
[info] -----> Deploying...
[info] remote: 
[info] remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/jvm-common.tgz... done
[info] remote: -----> sbt-heroku app detected
[info] remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
[info] remote: 
[info] remote: -----> Discovering process types
[info] remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
[info] remote: 
[info] remote: -----> Compressing...
[info] remote:        Done: 93.5M
[info] remote: -----> Launching...
[info] remote:        Released v11
[info] remote:        https://cloudrobe.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
[info] remote: 
[info] -----> Done
___________________________________________________________________________
```

Using "heroku logs" I can see:

```
2016-05-24T23:14:16.007200+00:00 app[web.1]: 23:14:16.006 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:5}] to localhost:33333
2016-05-24T23:14:16.370324+00:00 app[web.1]: 23:14:16.370 [main] INFO  o.f.s.servlet.ServletTemplateEngine - Scalate template engine using working directory: /tmp/scalate-5146893161861816095-workdir
2016-05-24T23:14:16.746719+00:00 app[web.1]: 23:14:16.746 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7a356a0d{/,file:/app/src/main/webapp,AVAILABLE}
2016-05-24T23:14:16.782745+00:00 app[web.1]: 23:14:16.782 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@7dc51783{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-05-24T23:14:16.782924+00:00 app[web.1]: 23:14:16.782 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @6674ms
```

But, 5 or 10 seconds later appears the following error showing that the connection has been timed out:

```
2016-05-24T23:52:32.962896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=cloudrobe.herokuapp.com request_id=a7f68d98-54a2-44b7-8f5f-47efce0f1833 fwd="52.90.128.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-24T23:52:45.463575+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

This is my Procfile using the port 5000:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/cloudrobe -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1
```

Thank you.

Comment: What version of sbt-heroku?

Comment: sbt version 0.13.9
Heroku plugin 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Your app is binding to port 8080, but it needs to bind to the port set as the `$PORT` environment variable on Heroku. To do this, you need to add `-Dhttp.port=$PORT` to your `Procfile`. It also needs to bind to 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1. So it might look like this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/cloudrobe -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0 -Dhttp.port=$PORT
```

Comment: I tried changing the Procfile as you say, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you redeploy after changing the Procfile?